# Dynamic element Coloring based on Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge

i'm looking to create an extension for our viewer that will let a user recolour the visible elements by a chosen property from the model.

I'm thinking the best way to do this is by creating a dynamic drop down of all the available property names, then when a user selects one i can colour all the objects based on the values of that property within each element.

my question is does anyone know the simplest way to create a dropdown of all the visible elements properties names ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it suits your requirement, it's the right way,
You can use parts from this sample: https://github.com/libvarun/forge-stacks

Comment: this is great and shows the possibility, I have managed no to get the visible element and a unique list of the attribute/property names. do you have any points on creating a popup/floating dropdown that would sit in front of the forge viewer rather than being a panel to the side.

Comment: please check this: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel